# Frobenius method on $x''+\frac{1}{t}x'+x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to use the Frobenius method on $x''+\frac{1}{t}x'+x=0$ where $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=0$. So far I have:

Let $x(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$ then $x'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nt^{n-1}\rightarrow \frac{1}{t}x'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{t}na_nt^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nt^{n-2}$

$x''(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2a_nt^{n-2}$

So if I put this into the ODE I get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg[n^2a_nt^{n-2}+na_nt^{n-2}+a_nt^n \bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg[a_n(n^2+n)t^{n-2}+a_nt^n \bigg] = 2a_1t^{-1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n(n^2+n)t^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n = 2a_1t^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+2}((n+2)^2+n+2)t^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n$

I can't figure out how to finish this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: you have to reindex the sums, so that there is $t^n$ everywhere, then you can identify the coefficients to $0$. You'll find a relation between the $a_n$.

Comment: Did I do that right above? Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes exactly, you get then $a_{n+2}((n+2)^2+(n+2))+a_n=0$ and $a_1=0$ if no calculation mistake (I did not verified prior calculations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may suggest, you can do the same without reindexing the sums
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n\qquad x'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_nt^{n-1}\qquad x''=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) a_nt^{n-2}$$ (please notice a small mistake in your $x''$).

Now, rewriting the differential equation $$x''+\frac{1}{t}x'+x=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) a_nt^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty n a_nt^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2 a_nt^{n-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n=0$$ Now, consider that you are looking for the term $t^k$. So, the term in first summation is such that $n-2=k\implies n=k+2$ and, in the second summation, it is just $n=k$.

So, for degree $k$, we have $$(k+2)^2a_{k+2}+a_k=0\implies a_{k+2}=-\frac{a_k}{(k+2)^2}$$

For sure, this implies that you force $a_1=0$; otherwise the solution is not valid (have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)) since, in principle, using Frobenius method, you need to work *the indicial polynomial*.